# Probability from a random pick.

Tags: probability, statistics

A test was given to a group of students. The grades and gender are summarized below

[image]

If one student is chosen at random from those who took the test,

Find the probability that the student got a 'C' GIVEN they are female.

> The total females is 43, total C's are 19
>   The total females who have a C is 5 of 19
>   So my answer is 5/19, is this wrong?

Comment: You've figured out the probability that the student is female, given that they got a C (you've taken the number of female C's and divided by the total number of C's).

Answer (score 2):

AHHH, I was reading it wrong.
The answer is 5/43.

I was reading, the probability that a student is female given they got a C.
which is 5/19